# How to extract line by line from a txt and pass each to 2 async functions?

Tags: .net, vb.net, txt

I have a txt with titles of songs one title below to the other and I'm looking to extract every single line at the time and make it work with 2 async functions.
These functions are 2:

- 1. using each line which correspond to a song title and search for it on youtube
- 2. adding that id to a playlist

Both of the functions are working, I used the Youtube Data API v3 and this is the code

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Reflection
 Imports System.Threading
 Imports System.Threading.Tasks
 Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
 Imports Google.Apis.Services
 Imports Google.Apis.Upload
 Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
 Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3
 Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data
 Public Class Form1
     Public id As String
     Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
         Try
             Await RetrieveID()
             Await PlaylistUpdates()
         Catch ex As AggregateException
    
             For Each inner In ex.InnerExceptions
                 MsgBox("Error: " & inner.Message)
             Next
         End Try
     End Sub
     Private Async Function RetrieveID() As Task
         Dim youtubeService = New YouTubeService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
             .ApiKey = "my api key ",
             .ApplicationName = Me.[GetType]().ToString()
         })
    
         Dim searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet")
         searchListRequest.Q = TextBox1.Text
         searchListRequest.MaxResults = 1
         Dim searchListResponse = Await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync()
    
         For Each searchResult In searchListResponse.Items
    
             id = searchResult.Id.VideoId
    
         Next
    
         MsgBox(id)
    
     End Function
     Private Async Function PlaylistUpdates() As Task
         Dim credential As UserCredential
    
         Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret_697184292163-n9c9etf5arv7iqkq6f84tlfqmjtfqi9g.apps.googleusercontent.com.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
             credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets, {YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(Me.[GetType]().ToString()))
         End Using
    
         Dim youtubeServiceo = New YouTubeService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
         .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
         .ApplicationName = Me.[GetType]().ToString()
     })
    
    
         Dim newPlaylistItem = New PlaylistItem()
         newPlaylistItem.Snippet = New PlaylistItemSnippet()
         newPlaylistItem.Snippet.PlaylistId = "PL4_Dx88dpu7cEY_cBjTZFFM1tVKF5Plsx"
         newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId = New ResourceId()
         newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.Kind = "youtube#video"
         newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId = id
         newPlaylistItem = Await youtubeServiceo.PlaylistItems.Insert(newPlaylistItem, "snippet").ExecuteAsync()
         MsgBox(id + " è stato inserito nella playlist")
     End Function
 End Class
```

but now how can I make the process automatically extracting line by line from a txt? as you can see at the moment I'm inserting into textbox1 the query, but I would like to make it automatically since I have at least 200 queries ( song titles ).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*note: I'm not familiar with VB's syntax, just with how .NET works.*

Looks like you just need file IO here. [This tutorial](https://www.technologyuk.net/computing/software-development/computer-programming/vbnet/simple-file-io.shtml) seems to go over it well enough. Basically, you'll want to create an `IO.StreamReader` and open your file. Then loop over the contents of the StreamReader with `ReadLine` until you can't anymore, and pass the values to your async functions.

Here's a console app that'll demonstrate the file IO:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim srdFile As IO.StreamReader
        Dim strLine As String
        srdFile = New IO.StreamReader("my_file.txt")
        Do Until srdFile.Peek = -1
            strLine = srdFile.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(strLine)
        Loop
        Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

---

Edit: Here's how I'd integrate it with the rest of your class:

Note how I'm not `await`ing on each of the async functions. Since your code doesn't rely on their output values, you can just proceed onwards and let the async do its thing. This is especially important with `Button1_Click`, as it's a UI event that needs to end as soon as possible.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RunExtract()
    End Sub
    
    Private Async Sub RunExtract()
        Dim srdFile As IO.StreamReader
        Dim strLine As String
        srdFile = New IO.StreamReader(Textbox1.Text)
        Do Until srdFile.Peek = -1
            strLine = srdFile.ReadLine()
            RetrieveID(strLine)
            PlaylistUpdates(strLine)
    End Sub
    
    Private Async Function RetrieveID(id as String) As Task
        'Do something with id 
    End Function
    
    Private Async Function PlaylistUpdates(id as String) As Task
        ' Do something with id
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, to read the txt won't be such a big issue, it's plenty of tutorials online, but my issue is how to pass each line to the functions...

Comment: also, your code seems to read a empty line before of the full one, eventho i don't have any first blank line..

Comment: No clue what's the issue with the empty line, sorry.

Comment: it gives you the same error with the empty line?

Comment: As I said in my note at the beginning of my answer, I don't use VB, so I can't actually test your code. The above is my best guess at the structure of a solution based on my experience with C#.NET. Furthermore, I don't know how Google APIs work, so I can't translate your VB code into C# APIs to test with.

Comment: it has nothing to do with google apis.. I've tried a simple txt file with 1 2 3 4 5 one under the other and as a first result it shows  a blank line to follow 1 etc

Comment: Ok, I've modified my first code block to be a console script. I successfully compiled and ran it on my computer and could not replicate your error.

Comment: That's working now i don't know why it gave me that problem.. Just one last thing.. SInce this method is quite fast, I think google api got a limit on how many request I can do per second.. Is there a way to slow it down a bit ? Also is possibile to delete the lines from the txt that have been already "read" by the software? many thanks

Comment: To wait on rate limiting, I'd use [`thread.sleep`](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/visual-basic/vb-thread-sleep)

Comment: that's actually what I was trying to avoid cause that cause the freezing of the form.. What about deleting the lines a la minute? do you think it would be possible? thanks

Comment: The form freezing is because you're doing long operations on the UI thread, not because there are long operations. Notice how in my example I removed the `await` commands, meaning that the UI thread doesn't *await* the completion of the called function before returning... It just fires it off and keeps chugging along. If you want, I can add some info about how threading works in VB