# How to delete a line from a txt after reading it

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, text-files

I need to delete a line from a txt after I read it.
To read line by line I use

```
Dim srdFile As IO.StreamReader

       srdFile = New IO.StreamReader("shazam.txt")
       Do Until srdFile.Peek = -1
           strLine = srdFile.ReadLine()

           ... how to delete the line here..
       ' here i call another function 
       Loop

       srdFile.Close()
```

How can I delete it the lines after they are being read? Also how can I save the file everytime i delete a line?. Thanks

Comment: That's not a good idea. You would have to delete the first line after reading and move all lines to the top afterwards, so basically you had to rewrite the whole file in each line. Thats not what you want. What you are really trying to accomplish? Why you can't process all lines first and afterwards delete or clear the whole file?

Comment: I need to read line by line, but with each line i need to pass it to a function. That's why the loop... Maybe i can insert all the lines into a richtextbox.. then would be easier to delete them after im "using" them?

Comment: @TimSchmelter look at my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73574865/how-to-extract-line-by-line-from-a-txt-and-pass-each-to-2-async-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good idea. You would have to delete the first line after reading and move all lines to the top afterwards, so basically you had to rewrite the whole file in each line. Thats not what you want. But you could process each line and determine which could not be processed successfuly. Then you can clear the file and write the remaing lines into that file:

```
Dim failResults = From line In IO.File.ReadLines(path)
                  Select result = (Line:=line, ProcessResult:=ProcessLine(line))
                  Where result.ProcessResult = False
                  Select result.Line
Dim remainingLines = failResults.ToList()
IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "")
IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, remainingLines)
```

Here's a method which you have to fill with your logic:

```
Private Function ProcessLine(line As String) As Boolean
    ' do something with this line and return if it was successful, so can be deleted
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for you answer. I'm not sure If I get it right, but I don't know what you mean with "processed successfuly".. all the line are processed successfuly.. If you could have a look to the link i've posted in the comments before, you can see I need to pass each line, one by one to a function. After the function does it jobs then I don't need the line anymore, that's why I want it to be removed.. If i close and open the software, if i don't remove the line that i've already processed, it will process again the same lines forever.. Hope now I explained better. Thanks

Comment: @adatoadaue: well if that method cannot have any issues or exceptions, then return true and the file will be cleared when you are finished. Maybe you have not seen yet that the LINQ query above also calls this methoid for each line.

Comment: what if the software crash for whatever reason? will the file still be saved?

Comment: Each line is processed at `failResults.ToList()`.  You should use a Try...Catch in ProcessLine(or whatever your method is called). Then you can return False if there was an error. These lines will be recreated at the end after the file was cleared.

If someone shuts down your computer in the line `failResults.ToList()` it's possible that you have processed some lines but they will not be deleted from the file. If it's so important you should use a database.